# $wpdb return empty with date selection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress calendar plugin, with possibility to add events attached to one date. Events are stored in a custom database that works fine.

But I've got troubles with a function in which I use a `'$wpdb->get_results'`
This function need a date as parameter.

This is my code:

```
function get_events_list($day) {

    global $wpdb
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "mytable";

    $events_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date = $day)", ARRAY_A );

    var_dump($events_list);

}
```

`'var_dump($events_list)'` returns an empty array, but I've got entries in the table.

I tried the function with no parameter, entering a well-formatted date directly in the SQL request, like that:

```
function get_events_list() {
    $events_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date = '2017-03-30')", ARRAY_A );
}
```

This works great.

I also did a `'var_dump($wpdb->last_query)'`, trying to find what happen.

Tested with no parameter (hard-coded '2017-03-30'), which is working fine, the last_query returns:

```
'SELECT * FROM wp_mytable WHERE date = '2017-03-30')'
```

With dynamic parameter, it returns the date without quote:

```
'SELECT * FROM wp_mytable WHERE date = 2017-03-30)'
```

I think I'm pointing the problem but cannot resolve it (I tried a lot of things).
Could someone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello_ mate,

first I dont't understand how could this (**'SELECT * FROM wp_mytable WHERE date = '2017-03-30')'**) query work, this final bracket looks very very strange to me :).

Anyway if your query is working fine then simply change:

```
$events_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date = $day)", ARRAY_A );
```

to

```
$events_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date = '$day')", ARRAY_A );
```

as you see we only put quotes when passing the variable.

Let me know if this works for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes that works with '$day'. It's so usual to me to cancatenate with some . (dots - or others) that I didn't even tried this way.
Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes man -

```
$events_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE date = '$day')", ARRAY_A );
```

without those quotes it is becoming  `WHERE date = 2017-03-30`